# Basic circuit advice to control a solenoid at different currents

Tags: constant-current, solenoid

I am looking to control a solenoid at approx 1.4 A, 0.7 A, and 0 A with a rocker switch and will need constant current capable of 100% duty cycle at these currents.

The supply voltage will be a 12 V battery so it will fluctuate slightly. I was looking at DRV8871 and just changing the current limiting resistor with the switch but came across a couple of other methods using transistors + voltage regulator and a MOSFET method. This was a little more enticing due to lead times. I have a background in ME so I am looking for a little advice to hopefully point me in the right direction.

Ref to other articles:

https://www.circuits-diy.com/solenoid-driver-circuit/

https://www.electronicdesign.com/industrial-automation/article/21806574/whats-the-best-way-to-drive-a-solenoid

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

The [DRV8871](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8871.pdf) is actually a brushed DC motor controller with programmable current limit, but it seems that this will cause the output to fluctuate between a maximum current and a nominal current using PWM.

A PWM drive is desired because of efficiency. But for simplicity, a linear current regulator might be good, using an LM317 adjustable regulator and a current sense resistor:

https://lednique.com/power-supplies/lm317-constant-current-power-supply/

Depending on the resistance of the solenoid, the power dissipation may be problematic. Assuming the solenoid draws 1.4 A at 10 V, and battery is 12 V, the sense resistor would be 1.25/1.4 = 0.89 ohms, and 1.75 watts. The LM317 would drop 1.75 volts and dissipate 2.45 watts.

For your other requirement, 0.7 A, the sense resistor would be 1.78 ohms, and will dissipate 0.87 watts. The solenoid would have 5 volts drop, so the regulator will see 12-6.25 = 5.75 V and dissipate 4.025 watts.

Comment: Great info and exactly what I was looking for!  With a solenoid resistance of about 4.4Ohms I calculated the following:

Comment: Great info and exactly what I was looking for!  With a solenoid resistance of about 4.4Ohms I calculated power dissipation of 3.98W at 1.4A and 3.27W at 0.7A.  As you pointed out the power dissipation would be the issue here I think.  The KCS appears to have the best thermal properties but I am still calculating a temp rise of close to 100C. This needs to be enclosed and sealed, but possibly I could have a heat sink potted that has exterior fins.  I haven't done enough research here so will investigate thermal characteristics next.

Comment: To control this ideally I would like to use a 3 button momentary switch but I don't know how that could be done so I assume a latching switch would be necessary to either change the sense resistance or run two circuits with different sense resistors.  Would you have a recommended approach?  Seems like one circuit would be lower cost.

Comment: You could use two latching pushbuttons - one to select between the two shunt resistors, and another for on/off, where the off position functions for zero amps.